# How to use phantomJS to open a sitelink using selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have installed *selenium webdriver* via *npm* by the following method:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\testPhantomJS>npm install selenium-webdriver
```

Then I have put the *phantomjs* scripts(codes) in the same folder location.

My folder now looks like the image given below:

[image]

#### Requirement:

I am trying to use headless Webkit of PhantomJS to open *google.com* through Selenium Webdriver but when I execute the following code system, some error occurs.

#### Script: test.js

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs())
    .build();
var baseUrl = 'http://google.com/';

driver.get(baseUrl);
driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
driver.quit();
```

I am running the code through command prompt using node.js

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\testPhantomJS\node_modules\selenium-webdriver >node test.js
```

After running this, I am getting some error, which is stated below:

#### Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to require the `By` tool seperately.

```
var By = require('selenium-webdriver').By;
```

Or you can use it like this: `webdriver.By.func()`

Comment: Holy Jesus!! You are a genius man! Now I am getting another error. Can you help me in that too?

Comment: I'd suggest to create another question with your new error and leave a link here. Or try to fix it yourself first. ;)

Comment: Ok... I am posting again.

Comment: Can you please help me in this issue too, for me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988495/how-to-use-phantomjs-for-opening-a-sitelink-using-selenium-webdriver