# How to use PhantomJS for opening a sitelink using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to use headless Webkit of PhantomJS to open google.com through Selenium Webdriver but when I execute the following code system, some error occurs. Have I missed something?

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var By = require('selenium-webdriver').By;
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs())
    .build();
var baseUrl = 'http://google.com/';
driver.get(baseUrl);
driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
driver.quit();
```

But I am getting a new error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Require `until` first:

```
var until = require('selenium-webdriver').until;
```

Comment: Is there any visible change? I mean something that I can see? It does not give any error, but I can't see any output too

Comment: You are not returning anything so I guess everything is working fine. It opens the page and processes your defined commands and exits afterwards. You might add some testing framework like Mocha to do some tests and get some results for success or failure.